# How to check for duplicates across multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df that looks like this:

```
ID    Lat    Long   geo
4     23     45     xyhj
5     23     12     nil
7     40     32.    kl
```

If I want to check duplicates across one column, I can use

```
df['Lat'].is_unique
```

This would give me `False`.

But is it possible to check if there are any rows where both, the `Lat` and `Long` values are being repeated? In the case of this data frame, the answer would be `True` because no combination of `Lat` and `Long` is duplicated.

Comment: did you mean something like:-  
`~df.duplicated(['Lat','Long']).any()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking duplicates from the entire dataset you can use, df.duplicated().sum().

You can also explicitly write the column names and get the duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You want `pd.DataFrame.duplicated(subset=<list_of_columns>)`:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df_original = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [4, 5, 7],
        "Lat": [23, 23, 40],
        "Long": [45, 12, 32],
        "geo": ["xyhj", "nil", "kl"],
    }
)
df_duplicated = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [4, 5, 7, 8],
        "Lat": [23, 23, 40, 23],
        "Long": [45, 12, 32, 12],
        "geo": ["xyhj", "nil", "kl", "something else"],
    }
)

for df in [df_original, df_duplicated]:
    print(df, "\n", df.duplicated(subset=["Lat", "Long"]).any(), "\n\n")
```

This prints

```
   ID  Lat  Long   geo
0   4   23    45  xyhj
1   5   23    12   nil
2   7   40    32    kl 
 False 


   ID  Lat  Long             geo
0   4   23    45            xyhj
1   5   23    12             nil
2   7   40    32              kl
3   8   23    12  something else 
 True
```